# How to allow Contributors to publish articles after approval

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I am trying to make a website with similar functionality to tutsplus (its a tutorial website where anyone can post a tutorial).

I thought it would be best to use WordPress and set the default role to contributor.
What do you think of this?

How can I make the contributor rank able to publish an article but have it then require the approval of an admin before it actually gets published to the website?

I look forward to your replies and answers, any help is humbly accepted.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make the contributor rank able to publish an article but
>   have it then require the approval of an admin before it actually gets
>   published to the website?

The "Contributor" role already behaves that way:

> #### Contributor
>
> - delete_posts
> - edit_posts
> - read
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor

As you see, that role lacks the `publish_posts` capability of the role just above it-- the "Author" role. Without that capability the "Contributor" can't publish but can only save drafts and edit.